# How Does Android Force Language or Locale Change?

Tags: android, configuration, locale

In android, when user changes the language of the device, every resource in my app changes to the resources related to the locale of the new language. Let's call this A.

Now in my android app, the user has the ability to select the language of the "app" (not the device), and every resource will need to change based on the new language. In some of my activities, the language and locale changes and everything is just like how A is. But in some other activities (like when the user is in password activity, the first activity the user needs to enter the password to go in the app), every resource is the same as the device's language.

How can completely force my app to change language/locale, just the way android does it in A?

I should add that when I change the device language, the password activity changes language as well.

Comment: You should read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: It did not help at all! I need to know how android does this in code that totally changes the locale of the app

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the android system? What are you planning on doing?

Comment: I'm planning on changing my activities language, to the language the user has set "in the app". (Not in the device, my app can set the language of the app)

Comment: I feel like the best solution for that would be to keep a locale object and check that whenever you update your UI

Answer (score 0):

You can call `attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper)`, and in the `wrap` method of your custom ContextWrapper you should have something like:

```
Configuration newLocaleConfig = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
Resources res = context.getResources();
newLocaleConfig.locale = newLocale;
Locale.setDefault(newLocale);
res.updateConfiguration(newLocaleConfig, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Be sure to check the implementation in different API Levels!